# Why I cannot see the dash mark between @param name and description?

Tags: eclipse, javadoc

I am using Ecliplse and when hovering my mouse over a method name e.g. Integer.*valueOf*(0);

the Javadoc gives me parameters info:

```
Parameters:
      i - an int value.
```

However, if I write my own method (and doc comment):

```
/**
* @param i an {@code int} value.
*/
public static void bar(int i) {
}
```

I would have the following when placing my mouse over my method name

```
Parameters:

      i an int value.
```

So, why the appeared "javadocs" (at mouse hover) are rendered with different format, even if I write exactly the same comment as found in the source file of java.lang.Integer?

I kind of dislike the sencond format with bold param names and would like to stick to the first format. Any way I can configure Eclipse to achieve that? Please could someone help me to demystify...Many thanks

Comment: I always get the second format, also for types from the class library. Maybe you have a JRE with a Javadoc attachment instead of source code? What does *Preferences > Java > Default JREs* look like?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The difference stems from the [individual templates (doclets) you can use when generating Javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/javadoc/doclet/overview.html). If Eclipse generates Javadoc (on-the-fly) from comments in code it obviously uses a template that omits the '-'. When Oracle generated the [official API documentation for the JRE](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#valueOf%28int%29) it used a template that generates a '-'.

So, why do you see a '-' in Eclipse when you browse JRE code but not in your own code? It seems like you configured the JRE in Eclipse (Window > Preferences > Java > Installed JREs) such that the Javadoc is available in the file system but the JRE source is not. Hence, Eclipse will show you the official Oracle version rather then generating it on-the-fly from source.

Comment: exactly as what you said. I have jre as my "installed JREs" which does not have source code attached. After pointing "installed JREs" to jdk which has both source code and doc attached, Eclipse chooses to generate Javadoc on the fly using the source code and the second format in my question appears.